# Splitting equation into multiple lines with `\[` of amsmath package

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have the following questionwith `\[` of amsmath package, and I would like to split it into multiple lines.

```
\[
TP_{apt} = \beta_0 +  \underbrace{\boldsymbol{D_{ap(t-1)} \cdot \beta}}_{\text{Dyad variables}} +
\underbrace{\delta MM_{apt}  }_{\text{Mismatch}}  + \underbrace{\eta Gap_{apt} }_{\text{Mismatch}}  +  \underbrace{\boldsymbol{A_{a(t-1)}\cdot \alpha}  + \boldsymbol{P_{p(t-1)}\cdot \gamma}  + \boldsymbol{N_{t}\cdot \theta}}_{\text{Controls}} + \underbrace{\varphi_{a} +\omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} +  \mu_{t}}_{\text{Fixed effects}} + \epsilon_{apt}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: `\[ ... \]` is meant for single-line equations.  Other environments are provided for multi-line displays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an `align*` environment and introduce a single line break.

I think you should also avoid making some subscripts bold while others remain non-bold. Hence, I'd limit the scope of the `\boldsymbol` directives to exclude subscript terms. To simplify inputs, you could load the `bm` package and use its `\bm` macro instead of `\boldsymbol`.

Also, in case your notational setup allows it, I'd replace `(t-1)` in the subscript terms with `,t-1`, of a less-busy "look". And, do make it clearer to readers that `TP`, `MM`, and `Gap` are variable names by, say, encasing them in `\mathit` wrappers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\usepackage{bm}      % for '\bm' macro
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}{}} % macro for displaying variable names

\begin{document} 

\begin{align*}
\vn{TP}_{\!apt} 
&= \beta_0 
   + {\underbrace{\bm{D}_{ap,t-1} \cdot \bm{\beta}}_{\textnormal{Dyad variables}}}
   + {\underbrace{\delta \vn{MM}_{apt}  }_{\textnormal{Mismatch}}}  
   + {\underbrace{\eta \vn{Gap}_{apt} }_{\textnormal{Mismatch}}}   \\
&\quad
   + {\underbrace{\bm{A}_{a,t-1} \cdot \bm{\alpha}  
                + \bm{P}_{p,t-1} \cdot \bm{\gamma}  
                + \bm{N}_{t} \cdot \bm{\theta}}_{\textnormal{Controls}}}
   + {\underbrace{\varphi_{a} +\omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} +  \mu_{t}}_{\textnormal{Fixed effects}}}
   + \epsilon_{apt}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Amazing solution. I used yours in my paper.

Answer (score 5):

With `aligned` math environment (defined in `amsmath` package) and `bm` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}
TP_{apt} = \beta_0 
    +{} &   \underbrace{\bm{D}_{ap(t-1)} \cdot \beta}_{\text{Dyad variables}} 
          + \underbrace{\delta MM_{apt}}_{\text{Mismatch}}  
          + \underbrace{\eta Gap_{apt}}_{\text{Mismatch}}  +   \\
        &   \underbrace{\bm{A}_{a(t-1)}\cdot\alpha 
                         + \bm{P}_{p(t-1)}\cdot\gamma
                         + \bm{N}_{t}\cdot \theta}_{\text{Controls}}
          + \underbrace{\varphi_{a} +\omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} + \mu_{t}}_{\text{Fixed effects}}
          + \epsilon_{apt}
    \end{aligned}
\]
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I forgot on curly braces after `+` sign. Corrected now. Thank you very much for all :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Amazing solution.

Answer (score 5):

The environment of choice for this kind of situation is `split`.

I'd use three lines for getting a better balance (but I wouldn't use `\boldsymbol` for emphasis).

Some notes before showing the code.

1. `\underbrace{...}_{...}` should be braced in order to get the correct spacing around `+` signs.
2. `Gap` should probably be upright, as it doesn't seem the product of three quantities, but a variable by itself. The same for TP and MM.
3. I added `\,`  between `\eta` and `\mathrm{Gap} to make the formula clearer.
4. Since the first row has three underbraces, they should be at the same height, which is achieved by adding a phantom bar that artificially makes the formulas to have the same depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\bs}{\smash[t]{\vphantom{\big|}}}% local command for this alignment
\begin{split}
\mathrm{TP}_{apt} = \beta_0
  &+ {\underbrace{\boldsymbol{D_{ap(t-1)} \cdot \beta}\bs}_{\text{Dyad variables}}}
   + {\underbrace{\delta \mathrm{MM}_{apt}\bs}_{\text{Mismatch}}}
   + {\underbrace{\eta\, \mathrm{Gap}_{apt}\bs}_{\text{Mismatch}}}
\\
  &+ {\underbrace{
       \boldsymbol{A_{a(t-1)}\cdot \alpha} +
       \boldsymbol{P_{p(t-1)}\cdot \gamma} +
       \boldsymbol{N_{t}\cdot \theta}
     }_{\text{Controls}}}
\\
  &+ {\underbrace{
       \varphi_{a} + \omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} + \mu_{t}
     }_{\text{Fixed effects}}}
   + \epsilon_{apt}
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't give "TP" and "MM" the same treatment as "Gap".

Comment: @Mico I don't really know whether they are individual variables or products.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your solution. they are individual variables (TP, MM, Gap). :)

Comment: @J.K. I fixed the code in view of your comment.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much for the follow-up!

Answer (score 3):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}
```

[image]

```
    \begin{multline*}
    TP_{apt} = \beta_0 +  \underbrace{\boldsymbol{D_{ap(t-1)} \cdot \beta}}_{\text{Dyad variables}} +
    \underbrace{\delta MM_{apt}  }_{\text{Mismatch}}  + \underbrace{\eta Gap_{apt} }_{\text{Mismatch}}  +\\
    \underbrace{\boldsymbol{A_{a(t-1)}\cdot \alpha}  + \boldsymbol{P_{p(t-1)}\cdot \gamma}  +
    \boldsymbol{N_{t}\cdot \theta}}_{\text{Controls}} + \underbrace{\varphi_{a} +\omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} +  \mu_{t}}_{\text{Fixed effects}} + \epsilon_{apt}
    \end{multline*}
```

[image]

```
    \begin{align*}
    TP_{apt} = \beta_0 +  \underbrace{\boldsymbol{D_{ap(t-1)} \cdot \beta}}_{\text{Dyad variables}} +
    \underbrace{\delta MM_{apt}  }_{\text{Mismatch}}  + \underbrace{\eta Gap_{apt} }_{\text{Mismatch}}  &+\\
    \underbrace{\boldsymbol{A_{a(t-1)}\cdot \alpha}  + \boldsymbol{P_{p(t-1)}\cdot \gamma}  +
    \boldsymbol{N_{t}\cdot \theta}}_{\text{Controls}} + \underbrace{\varphi_{a} +\omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} +  \mu_{t}}_{\text{Fixed effects}} + \epsilon_{apt}
    \end{align*}
```

[image]

```
    \begin{gather*} 
    TP_{apt} = \beta_0 +  \underbrace{\boldsymbol{D_{ap(t-1)} \cdot \beta}}_{\text{Dyad variables}} +
    \underbrace{\delta MM_{apt}  }_{\text{Mismatch}}  + \underbrace{\eta Gap_{apt} }_{\text{Mismatch}}  +\\
    \underbrace{\boldsymbol{A_{a(t-1)}\cdot \alpha}  + \boldsymbol{P_{p(t-1)}\cdot \gamma}  +
    \boldsymbol{N_{t}\cdot \theta}}_{\text{Controls}} + \underbrace{\varphi_{a} +\omega_{p} + \tau_{ap} +  \mu_{t}}_{\text{Fixed effects}} + \epsilon_{apt}
    \end{gather*}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Suggestion: put the `\underbrace` constructs in an additional set of braces, especially when they occur between binary operators. Spacing is quite messed up right now.

Comment: In your second solution, where you employ an `align*` environment, the spacing around the final `+`  symbol in row 1 looks off.